# How to download leakcanary-android aar file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, leakcanary

I want to use leakcanary-android aar file and don't want to use grade to download it, how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://search.maven.org/ and search for `leakcanary-android` there you will find the Download button from there you can download the aar file.

[image]

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: there is some timer or something says I cannot accept for that number of minutes, so sorry

Comment: that's strange no worries, accept whenever you can. thanks